# Algebraic dependency between an polynomial and its derivative.

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $x\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\psi(u)=(u+x-1)(u+x-3)^2(u+x)$ be a polynomial in $u$ with coeffients in the complex field. It is clear that $\psi(u)$ and its first order derivative
$$\psi'(u)=(u+x-1)(u+x-3)^2+2(u+x-1)(u+x-3)(u+x)+(u+x-3)^2(u+x)$$
are algebraically dependent since they are two polynomials in one variable.

I'm trying to find the polynomial in two variables, say $A(X,Y)$, such that

$$A(\psi(u), \psi'(u))=0,$$

which exists because of the algebraic dependence. Someone could give me a hint on how to find such polynomial $A$? It should be easy to solve with computational methods, but I don't have this expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two answers to [this theoretical question about algebraic dependence of univariate polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/189181/how-to-prove-that-two-univariate-polynomials-are-always-algebraically-dependent) are both suited to computation.

The first answer proves that there must be a linear relation among $\{\psi(u)^j\psi'(u)^k\colon 0\le j,k\le 4\}$ for example, and linear algebra on the coefficients of these polynomials can find the relation which becomes an algebraic relation between $\psi$ and $\psi'$.

I instead carried out the method of the second answer, namely calculating the resultant of two polynomials $\psi(u)-Y$ and $\psi'(u)-Z$, because I have software that calculates resultants as a black box  :)  The answer I obtained is
$$
\Phi(Y,Z) = Z^4+5 Z^3-54 Y Z^2-36 Z^2-256 Y^3+117 Y^2+864 Y,
$$
and my software also confirmed what we could by hand if we had to, namely that $\Phi\bigl( \psi(u),\psi'(u) \bigr) = 0$. (Interestingly this algebraic relation is uniform in the constant parameter $x$.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was expecting the parameter to appear in the final polynomial and it is actualy better than I expected.